# What is "flash data"?

Tags: node.js, session

I have been doing some tutorials around nodejs. One tutorial mentions a library called "connect-flash" that lets you set "flash data".

I have never heard of this term before could someone please define this? (I found the readme rather unhelpful)

Thanks

Comment: https://www.npmjs.org/package/connect-flash - "The flash is a special area of the session used for storing messages. Messages are written to the flash and cleared after being displayed to the user. The flash is typically used in combination with redirects, ensuring that the message is available to the next page that is to be rendered." (A little bit of research can answer most cursory questions.)

Comment: @user2864740 Why didn't you just make that an answer instead of a comment? you could've gotten some rep points for it...

Comment: @Jan Reputation is overrated - once I have my relevant stack exchange account high enough to get sufficient [editor] permissions I don't need any more :) While I know a lot of stuff, and know how to find a lot of stuff, I know a lot about very few things. I use comments to try and flush out details from questions and answers; in many cases about something I want to know more about.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's a type of user data that you show once and then destroy. Usually a top alert like "Your action has been successful" or similar.

By its nature it's dynamic, so it's saved in the user session and displayed in the very first rendered page, then discarded.

Answer (score 3):

Taken from the doc page for the [connect-flash library](https://www.npmjs.org/package/connect-flash) which seems fairly self-explanatory:

> The flash is a special area of the session used for storing messages.
>   Messages are written to the flash and cleared after being displayed to
>   the user. The flash is typically used in combination with redirects,
>   ensuring that the message is available to the next page that is to be
>   rendered.
>
> This middleware was extracted from Express 2.x, after Express 3.x
>   removed direct support for the flash. connect-flash brings this
>   functionality back to Express 3.x, as well as any other
>   middleware-compatible framework or application. +1 for radical
>   reusability.

...

> Flash messages are stored in the session. First, setup sessions as
>   usual by enabling cookieParser and session middleware. Then, use flash
>   middleware provided by connect-flash.